# Proper way to clean up HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, network-programming, inputstream

When I am done with an HttpURLConnection, does it matter which one I do

```
inputStream.close();
urlConnection.disconnect();
```

or

```
urlConnection.disconnect();
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: @mad.meesh That is exactly the opposite of the case. Don't post guesswork here.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the input stream is sufficient. If you disconnect you are disabling HTTP connection pooling.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 8344;
public static float FILE_SIZE = 0;
public static int SUM = 0;

public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //  String urlToDownload = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    int fileLength = 0;
    int size = 0;
    String urlarray[] = intent.getStringArrayExtra("url");
    ResultReceiver receiver = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
    URLConnection connection = null;
    int result = 0;

    try {
        URL url = null;
        for (String url_ : urlarray) {
            url = new URL(url_);
            connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            size = size + fileLength;
            //   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/ImageApp/");
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file1 = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file1);
            if (file1.createNewFile()) {
                file1.createNewFile();
            }
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                result = (int) (total * 100 / fileLength);
                Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
                  resultData.putInt("progress", result);
                receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }
            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
            SUM++;
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    FILE_SIZE = size / 1024;
    Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
    resultData.putInt("progress", 100);
    receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);

}


}
```

Comment: Why are you creating the output file three times? Poor quality code, with bugs, that does not answer the question in any way.